# Metodo asincrono en laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Hola tengo la siguiente función en laravel que diseña y guarda una factura en pdf. (usando dompdf)

```
public function designInvoice($products, $object, $path){
    $view = \View::make('pdf.invoice', \compact('object', 'products'))->render();
    $pdf = \App::make('dompdf.wrapper');
    $pdf->loadHTML($view);
    $pdf->save(public_path($path) . $object->id . '.pdf');

    return $view;
}
```

El problema es que en la linea donde guardo el pdf en su respectiva carpeta:

```
 $pdf->save(public_path($path) . $object->id . '.pdf');
```

Se tarda demasiado, a tal punto que a veces me da error de que se ha excedido el limite de tiempo y cuando si logra a completarlo se tarda al rededor de 50 segundos.

Y quisiera saber alguna forma de que esa funcion sea asincrona o hacer de sea propia del servidor osea que al ejecutarla quede ejecutanse en el servidor aunque se termine la ejecucion de la api.
De antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: si utilizas laravel puedes usar [queues](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queues)

Comment: @Bryro lo leeré gracias. Ojala resuelva mi problema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya hace días que encontré el problema y era el siguiente:

`Dompdf` no es bueno creando PDFs utilizando clases de `Bootstrap` es por eso que se tardaba tanto tiempo en renderizar.
Lo que hice fue omitir estilos Bootstrap y crear unos estilos CSS básicos. Al hacerlo el tiempo de carga se redujo a 2 segundos.

Otra alternativa puede ser:

Utilizando [Queues](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queues) en Laravel para disminuir el tiempo de renderizado de `Dompdf`

Así quedó mi función utilizando `Queues` para que la factura se genere en segundo plano:

```
    public function handle()
    {
        PDF::loadHTML($this->view)->save(public_path($this->path) . $this->id . '.pdf');
    }
```